# Upload documents to Access DB using c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, ms-access-2010

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 and I am trying to upload documents via a webpage to an access database.  I am not getting any errors when I run my code, but nothing is writing to the database.  Here is my on click code to show what I think it is supposed to do.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            if (fileExtension.ToLower() != ".doc" || fileExtension.ToLower() != ".docx" || fileExtension.ToLower() != ".pdf")
            {
                lblInfo.Text = "Only .doc, .docx, or .pdf files are allowed.";
                lblInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                int fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (fileSize > 2097152)
                {
                    lblInfo.Text = "Maximum file size of 2 MB exceeded.";
                    lblInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("Update STAFF SET Resume = @Resume WHERE StaffID=@StaffID", DBConnection);
                    update.Parameters.Add("@Resume", OleDbType.LongVarBinary).Value = FileUpload1.FileContent;
                    update.Parameters.Add("@StaffID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtStaffID.Text;
                    lblInfo.Text = "File Uploaded";
                    lblInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblInfo.Text = "Please select a file to upload";
            lblInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

If you could provide any advice or suggestions that would be great.  Thanks.  I will show the entirety of the code also, just in case it's an issue with the DB connection.

```
public partial class Staff : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter;
    DataTable LocalDataTable = new DataTable();

    private void ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        DBConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\CIS470_TPS_System\CIS470_TPS_System\CIS470_TPS_System\App_Data\TpsSystem_DB.mdb";
        DBConnection.Open();
        DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From STAFF", DBConnection);
        DataAdapter.Fill(LocalDataTable);
    }

    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToDatabase();
    }

    protected void AccessDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string requestId = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        txtSelectedStaff.Text = requestId; //this control holds the selected value
    }

    protected void DetailsView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, DetailsViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: This won't work, as you have just used OleDbCommand, but did not execute it. Try to execute using update.ExecuteNonQuery() before "lblInfo.Text = "File Uploaded";" line, and then check. ;)

Comment: @HiteshMistry Thanks for the suggestion, but after doing that I get an error when pressing upload.  It says InvalidCastException was handled by user code.  Failed to convert paramater value from HttpInputStream to a Byte[].

Comment: Hey Douglas, just write FileUpload1.FileBytes instead of FileUpload1.FileContent, try and let me know if it solves the problem. I could not do it as I do not have access installed on my machine. :|

Comment: @HiteshMistry Thank you.  That worked.  Now to figure out how to open it and read it, lol.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments to the question, we can use the FileUpload control's `.FileBytes` property to supply the value of the query parameter, as in this (simplified) example:

```csharp
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString =
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                @"Data Source=C:\__tmp\staffDb.accdb;";
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE STAFF SET Resume=? " +
                    "WHERE StaffID=?";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", FileUpload1.FileBytes);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", 1);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```